# combining excel and word VBA scripts. fso.CreateTextFile. Covert Word to text file

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, fso

I have the following part of a script that converts a Word document (Previously converted from a PDF) to a text file. This is usually a function as part of a larger script but for the purposes of this question this is fine.

```
Sub GetTextFromWord()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim oWd As Object, oDoc As Object
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set oWd = CreateObject("word.application")
    
    Set oDoc = oWd.Documents.Open("C:\temp\PDFs\XFA006HH - Granular Sulphamic acid - Univar - 19-05-2021.pdf.doc")

    filePath = "C:\temp\PDFs\" & "TEST" & ".txt"  'filename
    Debug.Print filePath
    'open text stream as unicode
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True)
                
    fileStream.Write oDoc.Range.Text
    fileStream.Close
    oDoc.Close

    oWd.Quit

End Sub
```

The TEST file generated is okay however lacks the subsection numbers that would normally be present.
[image]

When I generate the text file manually open the word doc. (File Export > Change file type > plain text (save). With options Windows Default selected, Insert line breaks unticked and allows for character substitution.

[image]

The generated text file is as desired.

[image]

When I record a macro in word for the same steps, I get the following script:

Sub Macro2()

```
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        "XFA006HH - Granular Sulphamic acid - Univar - 19-05-2021.pdf.txt", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False _
        , AllowSubstitutions:=True, LineEnding:=wdCRLF, CompatibilityMode:=0
End Sub
```

I would like to modify the first script to incorporate these parameters (mainly `InsertLineBreaks:=False, AllowSubstitutions:=True` - unsure if the others are required to generate the text file as exact). Ideally, I can incorporate as many as feasible to play around with and see the effect of the file generated. Things like `LockComments:=False, Password:=""` are not required.

How can I incorporate the script to achieve this?

fso.CreateTextFile doesn't appear to give such options so I wonder if I need to rethink this.

Link to Doc file:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsrLaUgt0KCLhiPc1u_vlYjFfsev?e=nlFn76

Update:

[image]

Comment: `CreateTextFile` does not have/accept such a parameter. This is what is able to do, unfortunately... You should proceed viceversa: To incorporate `SaveAs2` **instead of the VBScript object method**, which is faster but has some limitations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next updated code. It replaces the VBScript object method with the one you tested:

```
Sub GetTextFromWord()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim oWd As Object, oDoc As Object
    Const wdFormatText as Long = 2, wdCRLF as Long = 0

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set oWd = CreateObject("word.application")

    Set oDoc = oWd.Documents.Open("C:\temp\PDFs\XFA006HH - Granular Sulphamic acid - Univar - 19-05-2021.pdf.doc")

    Dim filePath As String: filePath = "C:\temp\PDFs\" & "TEST" & ".txt"  'filename
    Debug.Print filePath
    
    oDoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=filePath, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False _
        , AllowSubstitutions:=True, LineEnding:=wdCRLF, CompatibilityMode:=0
        
    oDoc.Close False
    oWd.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi this generates the Text file, but the text is completely encoded and unreadable. Not sure why this is happening as you have used the parameters as exactly given

Comment: @KJ Hm Nope still happening

Comment: Please see the update. [Content_Types].xml at the top?

Comment: @Nick Do you have any reference to the Word object? Please try (in Excel), in a separate testing sub: `Debug.Print wdFormatText`. What does it return in Immediate Window? Is it 2?

Comment: @FaneDuru Not getting anything returned for `Debug.Print wdFormatText` in the immediate window

Comment: @Nick This is good... I will adapt the code to 'inform' it about the used constants value. The code works in my environment and returned as it should. But I have a reference to `Word` object and it 'understood' the used constants value... I will do it in a minute. Please, try the updated code. Refresh the page (this one) to be sure that you are using the updated code. it only has a new code line: `Const wdFormatText as Long = 2, wdCRLF as Long = 0`... If there are special characters which looks to be transformed in something strange, try using `65001` (UTF-8) for `Encoding` parameter.

Comment: Appears to be working as required. Thank you!

Comment: @KJ I dont think this is an issue? Im still interested in using Poppler but this had proven very useful to my purpose

Comment: oh gosh i must have uploaded the wrong one, still working though